# Resample Pandas DataFrame with logical True/False aggregation

Tags: python, pandas, aggregate, resampling

Sorry if the title is not immediately clear but I can't think of a good way to frame it.

I want to do some advanced logic when resampling a DataFrame per day.

So I have a DataFrame named `trades` like this:

```
                         agg_tradeid    price  quantity  fst_tradeid  \
timestamp                                                              
2017-12-08 06:03:13.653            0  0.00023     100.0            0   
2017-12-08 06:08:00.292            1  0.00030    1999.0            1   
2017-12-08 06:09:05.218            2  0.00035    3339.0            2   
2017-12-08 06:09:17.911            3  0.00035     206.0            3   
2017-12-08 06:10:13.633            4  0.00033    1533.0            4   

                         lst_tradeid      timestamp     buy best_price  
timestamp                                                               
2017-12-08 06:03:13.653            0  1512712993653    True       True  
2017-12-08 06:08:00.292            1  1512713280292    True       True  
2017-12-08 06:09:05.218            2  1512713345218   False       True  
2017-12-08 06:09:17.911            3  1512713357911   False       True  
2017-12-08 06:10:13.633            4  1512713413633   False       True
```

And I want to resample to daily (`'1D'`) in a somewhat complex manner.

- `price: ohlc`
- `quantity: sum`
- create a new column, `ract` that will be the `quantity` where `buy==True` divided by the total resampled `quantity` for `1D`.

It's the last point that is giving me trouble, I can do the other 2 simply with:

```
trades.resample('1D').agg({'price':'ohlc', 'quantity':'sum'})
```

Comment: When there is multiple buy==True conditions, what do you consider when resampling?

Comment: The sum of all `quantity` for the desired timeperiod (i.e. `1D`) where `buy==True`, divided by the sum of all `quantity` for the desired timeperiod (regardless of the `buy` variable)

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful. Edited my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can compute `ract` separately using a temporary variable and assign the result back:

```
i = df.assign(v=df.quantity.where(df.buy))\
      .resample('1D')[['v', 'quantity']]\
      .sum()

j = df.resample('1D').agg({'price':'ohlc', 'quantity':'sum'})
j['ract'] = i.v / i.quantity

j

              price                            quantity      ract
               open     high      low    close quantity          
timestamp                                                        
2017-12-08  0.00023  0.00035  0.00023  0.00033   7177.0  0.292462
```

Comment: Excellent, this is it. Thank you.